# Getting an attribute value from the element above the selected element html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually I want to get the attribute value from the closest element. I am unable to get attribute value from my desired element. This is what I have done so far. 
I have searched a lot and hardly came up with anything useful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="grid mask">
        <figure>
            <div>
                 <h4>Hello There</h4> 
                 <span data-id="1"></span>
            </div>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="../dist/img/team/subhan.png" alt="">
            <figcaption> 
                <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" onclick="alert($(this).closest('span').attr('data-id').html())">Find</a>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `closest()` in jQuery means the closest **containing** element. The `span` doesn't contain the `a`.

Comment: so closest() don't  work for elements above?

Comment: No, it doesn't. How flexible do you need to be in the relationship between the `a` and the `span`? Are they always organized like the above DIV?

Comment: they are always in the same manner. but they are dynamically set on page through php with different data, thats why i thought closest might be useful in  order to capture click on every div.

Comment: `$(this).parent().parent().find('span').eq(0).data('id')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use more specific DOM traversal functions. Also, you shouldn't use `.html()`; `.attr()` returns the value of the attribute as a string, not an element that you need to extract the contents of.

```js
$("a").click(function() {
    alert($(this).closest('figure').find('span[data-id]').data('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="grid mask">
    <figure>
      <div>
        <h4>Hello There</h4> 
        <span data-id="1"></span>
      </div>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="../dist/img/team/subhan.png" alt="">
      <figcaption>
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Find</a>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much man. Its great to have people like you here :D :D
It worked!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/incrediblex/e27r8/693/
Here is my further work. I want to set href of the element <a> to the id got from data-id attribute and its working fine but only for the first element. Please review my fiddle. Thanks

Comment: IDs have to be unique. Use `class="offer-view"` instead of `id="offer-view"`.